# EC2 retirement - Meteor / MongoDB

Tags: amazon-ec2, mongodb, meteor

I am hosting my Meteor Application on an Amazon EC2 instance. Today I got a mail that my instance is scheduled for retirement until the end of month. I don't have any experience with that and what are the best ways to handle the situation.

My root device type is ebs.

Amazon suggests: "We recommend that you launch replacement instances and start migrating to them."

I already created an AMI Image of my instance and launched it. Unfortunatly my app can't be reached. At the moment the running instance can be reached via web and ssh. Is there any best practice?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Since your root drive is EBS not ephemeral you are in good place to be. What is the difference and why EBS is better?

Amazon EC2 instance with ephemeral drive is stateless, you can reboot but you can't stop. Reboot or terminate are only options that available.

Amazon EC2 instance with EBS is statefull so Stop state is supported. Followed by subsequent Start event your EC2 is about to start on new hardware. It basically means no data lost and you can replicate the exact instance state on new hardware and this is what you need.

Amazon AMI is a snapshot of EBS, there is nothing more under the hood.

Once you have another machine up and running you need to connect via SSH and check everything is running exact the same way. If something failed this is the time for automation and making disaster recovery plan. You still have plenty of time and running original machine so consider yourself as very lucky person.